# Как в .NET 6 настроить конфигурацию CQRS

Tags: .net, .net-core

Как в .NET 6 произвести конфигурирование CqrsEngine по подобию .NET 5(пример на скрине)? Не понимаю, как передать параметр CqrsEngine в .NET 6
[image: Пример конфигурирования CQRS в .NET 5]

Comment: CqrsEngine - это ваш класс, или вы использовали стороннюю библиотеку?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Это сторонний класс, не имеющий наследований и реализующий интерфейсы

Comment: Как называется библиотека, и чего вы пытаетесь добиться, используя ее?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko К сожалению, этой библиотеки нет в отрытом доступе, поэтому вы не сможете проверить, мне нужно разобраться как прокинуть обычный класс в Program, как на скрине в NET 5, чтобы я смог выполнить конфигурирование в NET 6

Comment: Этот cqrsEngine потом должен быть доступен внутри контроллера? Или он в бекграунде работает как-то?

Comment: текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: @AndreiKhotko Нет, он не должен быть доступен в контроллерах, он должен быть доступен в .NET 6 в Program (Тут теперь Startup) после строчки:

`// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.`

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, `CqrsEngine` зарегистрирован как сервис в `IServiceCollection`. Тогда, чтобы получить зарегистрированный объект `CqrsEngine`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<CqrsEngine>(); // Здесь регистрируете CqrsEngine как вам нужно

var app = builder.Build();

// Получаем cqrsEngine объект и выполняем метод
var cqrsEngine = app.Services.GetRequiredService<CqrsEngine>();
cqrsEngine.Start();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

...
```